# Button with centered text and left aligned image

Tags: html, css

i need some advice on how to properly center text and left or right position images within an 'a' tag.

the goal is to have button with:
- left aligned image
- text centered horizontally but left aligen if more lines of text
- all elements should be centered vertically.
- must work on most modern browsers (ex. IE below 9 does not matter)
- only using CSS

i made an exampel which seems to work with static heights (ex. 100px)
here's my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CtH9k/5819/

--

but how does i make this work properly width dynamic heights, especially the text is giving my problems.

```
 line-height: 100%;
```

here's my fiddle with dynamic heights https://jsfiddle.net/CtH9k/5820/

any good advices on what i may be doing wrong, perhaps some great tutorials or thoughts on this topic.

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/0h9kx91f/.  just use `a{display:table-cell;...}`

Answer (score 1):

First, be carefull. When you use `position:absolute` you have to add `position:relative` to the parent you want to position your element with. In your first jsfiddle it looked like it's working because your `a`, `div` and `body` are in the same position. In the second, your image gets "lost" because you added a span wrapper.

You can use this css:

```
top:50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

With both absolute and relative position and you will always be sure that whatever the container or your element height it will always be centered.

so I added these properties to your current ones:

```
.spanText {    
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.imgWrapper{
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

a {position:relative;}
```

and it's working (try changing the "200px" height to whatever you wish:

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/CtH9k/5826/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
 <div>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="imgWrapper">
                <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_11e745804f61_128.png" /></span>
        <span class="spanText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/CtH9k/5822/)

Answer (score 0):

Try flexbox.

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

a .textWrap {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_11e745804f61_128.png" />
            <span class="textWrap">
                 <span class="spanText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
            </span>
        </a>
  
  <a href="#">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_11e745804f61_128.png" />
            <span class="textWrap">
                 <span class="spanText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
```